# How can I prevent state updates infinite loops in react

Tags: reactjs

I pass data from child to parent component but it does not set in the state. when I try to setState, it give me an error

"Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. "

```
class Listing extends Component {
    state = {
        list: ''
    }
    update = (data) => {             
        this.setState({list: data }) 
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <Pagination
               data={this.update}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Pagination extends Component {
    state = {
        page : this.props.page,
        count : 0,
        perPage: this.props.perPage
    }  
    render() {
        const { page, count, perPage} = this.state
        const dataForParent = Object.values(page).slice(count*perPage, count*perPage+perPage);
        this.props.data(dataForParent)

        return (
            <div className="project-pagination m-top-30">

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the Pagination component is calling your update function as soon as it renders. The data prop does not look like a passive-event listener. Are you sure you're not suppose to pass it in an array of data instead?

Comment: You need to show an example of what `Pagination` does

Comment: I need to replace data on list state use "setState" but i can not do this

Comment: Yes, your goal is already clear. But your code doesn't make sense: you're not passing any data to the component, you're passing a function that sets the state of its parent, and the data is never passed to the component. Again, you need to show the code for the `Pagination` component or tell which library you're importing it from. Otherwise it's very hard to tell how to fix it.

Comment: data available in the data parameter. when I used setState it`s execute minimum 50 times and then it`s give me error

Comment: Yes, again, it is clear for everyone what the problem is and what's happening. But you really need to show the code to `Pagination` (or tell where you're importing it.) Is there some particular reason why you refuse to do so?

Comment: I included pagination page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Code

```
class Listing extends Component {
        state = {
            list: {}
        }
        update = (data) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({list: {...data} })
            }, 1000)
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            this.update()
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <Pagination
                    data={this.update}
                />
            )
        }
    }
```